# Why does isNumeric(string) crash in a while loop with a compound conditional statement?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Today I was working an in-class project with my students when I ran into this bug.

[Imgur Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2UPm.png)

[Pastebin Link](http://pastebin.com/tQHa4nMV)

Basically, `decTemperature` is a String variable that receives an input from the User. In order to teach data validation, short-circuiting, and loops, we were using the following `While` loop condtionals to force a valid response:

`While IsNumeric(decTemperature) = False Or 
       Convert.ToDecimal(decTemperature) <= 0.0 Or
       Convert.ToDecimal(decTemperature) > 135.0`

If the user puts in 'abc', *in theory* the conditional statement should short circuit before reaching the second part of the conditional statement. I attempted the conditional a number of different ways, but ultimately it would crash in every design.

My assumption on the issue probably links closely to [an older question I asked about dealing with data types with explicitly setting Option Strict 'on'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150375/why-does-visual-basic-allow-strings-to-be-added-to-integers-in-arithmetic-statem) (although a quick add of `Option Strict On` in the above code still crashes). That is to say, `decTemperature` is being processed in each conditional statement before evaluating.

Whatever the case, what is causing the issue and what would be a better approach that still maintains the concepts (that is forcing a valid response from the user)? I have an idea with using a Boolean data type `validResponse` and setting it, but that seems to be throwing away short-circuiting as a concept.

Comment: Try `OrElse` to short-circuit.  I would convert that to a real decimal outside of the while-loop with Decimal.TryParse.  This does not look like vb6.

Comment: 'Or' and 'And' in VB (any version) never short-circuited.  Only 'OrElse' and 'AndAlso' have this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Or` does not short-circuit.  Neither does `And`

`OrElse` does short-circuit (as well as `AndAlso`).  See [OrElse Operator (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea1sssb2.aspx)

So it should look like this:

```
While IsNumeric(decTemperature) = False OrElse _
      (Convert.ToDecimal(decTemperature) <= 0.0 OrElse _
       Convert.ToDecimal(decTemperature) > 135.0)
```

I would consider using [Decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) to test the validity of the input.

Comment: Yup, this does it. While our book does mention them, they are mentioned in passing and referred to as "lesser used logical operators".

Answer (score 1):

If you just use `Or` then every statement is evaluated in every case. That's what the short circuit operators `OrElse` and `AndAlso` are for. If you use `OrElse` the If statement stops the evaluation after the first true statement is detected (or the first false statement in case of an `AndAlso`).

So in your case the conversion to decimal would be executed in any case. This is avoided with the short circuit operators.